# How to move to the next screen when the image drops onto when I tap the button?

Tags: ios, image, button, tap

I wrote the animation concept  in viewDidLoad method i wrote:

```
    scaleFactor=2;
    angle=180;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10,10,45,45);
    UIView *box;
    box=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    box.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images673.png"];
    [self.view addSubView:box];
```

// This code is for the touch event of an object in the screen
// For the object movement i wrote the method which is shown below:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
        {
        UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:self.view];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UICiew setAnimationDuration:1];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        box.center=location;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
```

// And then,now i wrote a button which has to navigate to another class file// General navigation principle i wrote

```
-(IBAction)settings:(id)sender
{
aScreen *abc=[[aScreen alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:abc animated:YES];
[abc release];
}
```

Now the object is moving where i tap on the screen,but when i tap on the button,the image is not placing on the top of the button.What to do.Please help me.I took an image and then I made some animation for it to move till where I tap in the screen. But at the same time, I took a button and I wrote a button event action in viewcontroller. When I tap the button, the image is not moving onto the button.

What I want to do is if I tap the button, the image has to drop onto the button and it should display the next view controller. Can anyone help me in doing so? How to move to the next screen when the image drops onto when I tap the button?

Comment: Some body help me how to proceed further please

Comment: can you show us any code to follow what you are doing better? what do you mean drop onto the button? do you mean it is just placed on top of the button or becomes part of the button?

Comment: it has to just placed on the top of the button and the image has to be disappeared and then the button event action has to be fired

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i fully understand the problem without seeing your code but cant you do something like this?

```
-(ibaction)buttonevent:(id)sender{
cgrect frame = image.frame;
frame.origin.x = button.frame.x;
frame.origin.y = button.frame.y;
image.frame = frame;
image.alpha = 0;

[self pushviewcontroller:newViewcontroller animated:yes];
}
```

Comment: Am new to stack overflow Please excuse me,Please some one edit my question into a specific manner

Comment: see glogic above i posted the code.I think u dont understand.Please Can you check out patiently.

Comment: But when i write the code which i wrote in viewDidLoad method in IBAction method,the image was tapping but infinite images are displaying and moreover the screen navigation is not done.What to do.Where am i doing wrong in this situation

Answer (score 0):

hi try this code i have checked. This is working for me when you check for button and the image you are dragging intersect then fire the method where it moves to next screen

```
// Handles the continuation of a touch.
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{  
//NSLog(@"touchesMoved");
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if ([touch view] == mKey) {

    NSUInteger touchCount = 0;

    // Enumerates through all touch objects
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        // Send to the dispatch method, which will make sure the appropriate subview is acted upon
        [self dispatchTouchEvent:[touch view] toPosition:[touch locationInView:self.view]];
        touchCount++;
    }

}



}

// Checks to see which view, or views, the point is in and then sets the center of each moved view to the new postion.
// If views are directly on top of each other, they move together.
-(void)dispatchTouchEvent:(UIView *)theView toPosition:(CGPoint)position
{

// Check to see which view, or views,  the point is in and then move to that position.

if (CGRectContainsPoint([mKey frame], position)) 
{
     NSLog(@"touchesMoved");
    mKey.center = position;

}


if(CGRectIntersectsRect([mKey frame], [inVisible frame]) && k==0)
{
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    NSLog(@"thirdPiew frame");

    [inVisible setHighlighted:YES];
    [inVisible setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    k=1;
    [self performSelector:@selector(modalPresentationButtonPressed:)];    

}
}
```